# DDD, Unit of Work... without Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ms-access, data-access-layer

I am starting a new project and I want it to follow the DDD principles. I've read a lot about Entity Framework 4.0, IPOCO (T4 templates), DDD... but I cannot use EF because it doesn't support Microsoft Access (yes, I know it's not a good option, but it's a requirement of the project)

Could you confirm that EF doesn't support Access?

How can I implement a good DDD without using EF and with tools to easily map my DB tables to classes?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NHibernate.  There exists an [open source JetDriver](https://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.JetDriver/) that [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) can use in order to communicate with Access.

Comment: Has NHibernate tools to easily map DB Tables to classes, without having to edit hundreds of XML files? Are there any sample of using Unit of Work pattern with this ORM? Thank you

Comment: The NHibernate ISession object implements the Unit of Work pattern.  As for the mapping: you can use FluentNHibernate which allows you to create your mappings in code.  AFAIK, there exists no visual design tool to create your mappings.